# ¿Se recurre a la retórica y otros recursos lingüísticos embellecedores con más frecuencia en español que en inglés?

Tags: lingüística, escritura

¿Será que los hispanoablantes nativos hacemos más uso de recursos literarios en chats, foros etc. que como se acostumbra en el idioma inglés? ¿A qué se deberá esto?

**Actualización:**

Por ejemplo al hacer una busqueda avanzada en 
[WordReference Forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/).

Primero en español, buscando por la palabra "hola", y ordenando por el mayor numero de respuestas, obtenido:

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=209392&highlight=hola

Y luego en inglés, buscando por la palabra "Hi", y ordenando de la misma forma:

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=87385&highlight=hi

Luego de leer algunos comentarios, no puedo evitar tener un sentimiento generalizado, de que en español se usan mas fraces que no brindan informacion adicional dentro del contexto, sino que sirven más bien para "embellecer".

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, ¿estás preguntando o afirmando?

Comment: Te sugiero que edites la pregunta para hacerla más clara y comprensible, dando más información.

Comment: Gracias, he agregado información que podría ayudar a clarificar

Comment: Podría ser que la mayoría de quienes publican en inglés, tienen ese idioma como segunda lengua, y no hacen uso de la retorica con tanta frecuencia por no saber si es aplicable dentro del contexto.

Comment: BTW, el uso de mayúsculas para los nombres de idiomas es algo del inglés. No es un estilo correcto en castellano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, los hablantes *nativos* del inglés usan el lenguaje retórico con mayor frecuencia y más propiedad que la mayoría de los hablantes *nativos* del castellano.

Todo se reduce a la educación. En general, una persona nacida y educada en USA, el Reino Unido e Irlanda, Australia, Nueva Zelandia, Sur Africa y paises aledaños (los únicos que pueden ser llamados *hablantes nativos*) reciben en comparación con los hablantes del castellano, una mejor formación en gramática y literatura de su propio idioma durante los ciclos de educación básica. Esto también se aplica a hablantes bilingües de nivel 4 y 5 (nivel 5 es alguien que habla un segundo idioma con el mismo conocimiento, habilidad y fluidez que un hablante nativo). Esto no quiere decir que en general los angloparlantes escriban o hablen su lengua mejor que nosotros los hispanohablantes. La mayoría falla en el intento, igual que nosotros.

Hay muchos factores. Solo quiero mencionar un par:

Primero, los hablantes nativos de la lengua inglesa tienden a **leer mucho más** que los de lengua castellana, por tanto, su habilidad y comando del lenguaje es mayor simplemente por que se exponen más a formas literarias del lenguaje.

Segundo, los datos que ofreces no son indicativos de la realidad pues el inglés es la lengua franca de Internet y en un foro sobre la lengua inglesa encontrarás que la gran mayoría de quienes participan no son hablantes nativos. Cuando tu eres un hablante nativo o un bilingüe avanzado lo detectarás inmediatamente.

Comment: Son bastante interesantes esas aseveraciones, me gustaria encontrar mas informacion al respecto.

Comment: Vorbote, esa no debe ser la actitud. Siempre hay gente que va a estar en desacuerdo, no debemos tomarnolos tan en serio. ¿Ademas quien es user934? Nadie importante en este sitio, solo ve su reputación. Yo he visto tu activa participación y muchas respuestas han recibido votos positivos de parte mia. Ojala que lo reconsideres y te podamos seguir viendo por aqui.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio Gracias por tu comentario. Después de leerlo y tomarme un espacio para meditarlo te concedo la razón, así que seguiré participando. Sin embargo, no puedo consentir que se permita la participación de personas de tan baja calidad humana. Soy inexperto en los asuntos de administración de la comunidad, seguramente debí elevar mi queja a meta y dejar que los moderadores tomasen las medidas correspondientes. Bueno, esto es ya agua que corrió bajo el rio.

Comment: Lo siento, vorbote, pero estoy en desacuerdo con tu opinión y además me parece que no has interpretado correctamente la pregunta. Tu respuesta no me parece útil.

Comment: @Albertus Más bién eres tú quién no ha comprendido el contexto de mi respuesta. Y me temo que el de la pregunta. Leyendo tu propia respuesta, puedo ver claramente a donde vas y de donde vienes con tu posición que no discuto. Esto no es un problema de la lengua castellana solamente, la vacuidad de la literatura francesa y la alemana pueden ser igual o peor, especialmente cuando no hay traductor de por medio. La vanidad imperial española si es mas grande, vista desde America. Pero **no estamos hablando de literatura** sino de **el uso corriente por la gente de a pié**.

Comment: @vorbote Pensándolo mejor, tienes razón en que no he interpretado bien la pregunta, de forma que mi respuesta no es adecuada...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que voy a decir podría ser polémico.

Mi respuesta a tu pregunta es que sí, que existe en la literatura española y quizá también en la lengua hablada una tradición de exceso de retórica que no se percibe con la misma intensidad en la lengua inglesa.

No es un problema inherente a la lengua, pero me parece innegable que la escritura castellana ha pecado históricamente de afectación.

Es esa misma afectación que, por nombrar a alguien, Santiago Ramón y Cajal observaba en sus colegas científicos españoles, cuando los comparaba con los de otros países europeos. La afición a las palabras huecas ha sido un gran pecado histórico de los hispanohablantes, por suerte con innumerables excepciones, desde luego.

Digo todo esto porque participan en este foro muchas personas que no son nativas del idioma español y que al percibir la afectación de la que hablo podrían pensar que hay algo en nuestro idioma que lo inclina a la verbosidad, por comparación con la concisión del inglés. Creo que no es verdad, es solamente un problema de las personas, no de la lengua.

Comment: Tendrías el link de las observaciones de Santiago Ramón y Cajal sobre el idioma español. Te refieres a la [carta](http://revistademetalurgia.revistas.csic.es/index.php/revistademetalurgia/article/download/909/922) de Dr. Santiago explicando los beneficios del idioma español como medio de expresión científico?

Comment: No es polémico, ese problema de palabras huecas existe aunque yo creo que no se da en todos los ámbitos pero sí en algunos muy comunes como el lenguaje periodístico formal, especialmente en TV, que se pega fácilmente y se plasma sobre todo en el lenguaje escrito. Pero esto no es exclusivo del español. En inglés, sobre todo en EEUU, existe una tradición de escritura 'straightforward' mucho más marcada que en inglés de Inglaterra. Comparese el estilo general de 'Newsweek' (USA) y 'The Economist' (UK)

Comment: @rraallvv. Es muy interesante la carta que mencionas. Gracias por el enlace. En cuanto a la fuente de mi comentario, es un tema ampliamente tratado por Don Santiago en su obra "Los tónicos de la voluntad", publicada por Espasa-Calpe en la Colección Austral. De esta obra poseo un ejemplar de la undécima edición (1986). Se trata en su mayor parte de una colección de consejos a los jóvenes investigadores. Es todavía un libro de grata lectura, aunque le pesan los años, especialmente en lo que concierne a su concepción del papel subordinado de las mujeres respecto a los hombres.

Comment: @DeStrangis Mira qué curioso: si yo afirmo que el tema es polémico, y tú niegas que lo sea, incurres en paradoja al polemizar conmigo. Bromas aparte: No es un mero problema de palabras huecas. Es una tradición secular de pedantería que afecta a la historia entera de las letras españolas. Y que todavía pesa, por ejemplo, sobre el lenguaje científico en español.

Comment: @Albertus Bastante interesante, gracias por el link.